# What is \(\mathrm{Z_0F}\) with Vaught?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

In the beginning of Chapter VII of Robert Vaught, Set Theory - An Introduction (2nd ed.), Springer, 1995, ISBN 978-0-8176-4256-3, the author writes: "In this chapter we always work in ```Z_0F''' unless otherwise indicated. Thus Chapter 1 and §1 of Chapter 5 are available as we begin."

What, precisely, does ```Z_0F''' signify here? I would like to see the precise definition, and do not succeed with locating it.

Edit 1: In the comments section it was asked whether I had looked in the index, and I indeed did: (Z_0F) is not in the index.

Edit 2: the location I indicated also has "Thus Chapter 1 and §1 of Chapter 5 are available as we begin.", and this was added to the original question.

Comment: Presumably it's a book that has an index. Have you looked to see where this is mentioned first? That may very well give you a clue as to what going on. Just randomly guessing, perhaps page 67 contains the answer?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, and it is not in the index.  However, the location I indicated also has "Thus Chapter 1 and §1 of Chapter 5 are available as we begin." I edit this in to the question now.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks, there was a statement that contained an equation to find the solution on the top of page 67. It had provided a wholly correct answer if Zermelo set theory had had the axiom of Regularity. But if we are lenient and accept the statement that Z has Regularity, as well as Infinity, then \(Z_0\) is \(Z\) minus regularity and infinity. So \(Z_0F\) is Zermelo Fraenkel minus regularity and infinity.